# Codeigniter 404 can't find index.php (only on real server, not on virtual server)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-url

I got a working webpage with CodeIgniter. I did now just upload it to my webserver and it gives me a 404 error.

The browser address is "web-page.com/folder/en/about"

The baseurl in the config is "web-page/folder/"

Also this is in the config.php, I did try AUTO but it does not work either.

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "QUERY_STRING";
```

The index.php is in "web-page.com/folder/"

My htaccess is in "web-page.com/folder/.htaccess"

The content of the .htaccess is

```
AddCharset utf-8 .css .html .xhtml
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase  /folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|media|layout|css|libs|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Do you have any tip, any idea, what can I try to do? I did check all the rights, even with 777 it does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Lukas

Comment: Check if mod_rewrite is on on your server.
I had a problem like that a while ago and turns out that mod_rewrite was not present.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the idea, but mod_rewrite is definitly activated on my server. I did try a different server and it does not work there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, stupid, stupid me. I got it.

The error was in my "routes.php" I hadt to lowercase the default controller from

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Base";
```

to:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "base";
```

My offline server did work with it though. Thanks for the support.

Comment: I have the same problem, but this did not work for me. i'm stumped don't know whats wrong.

Comment: It's a case sensitivity issue. Lower-case your controller file names. eg "Contact.php" -> "contact.php". I'm assuming you develop on windows, host on linux?

Answer (score 2):

I know this should be a comment, but apparently I don't have enough rep yet.  Who is your web host?  That could sometimes throw a wrench in the whole process.

I know GoDaddy requires some different config settings for CodeIgniter to work right without the 'index.php'.

If it is, you'll need to change your uri_protocol config item to QUERY_STRING.

You can leave your index_page setting blank, but you'll need to update your htaccess file to something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: Something I forgot to mention... Even if your host isn't GoDaddy, you may want to give this a try because it will only take a minute.

Comment: Sadly enough it did not work out. I always get the same message.
But I just found out. If I have an error in my .htaccess it is saying it can't find index.php while if the htaccess is correct there is an 404 error. This means, it does find the index php, does it not? There is something else missing probably.

Answer (score 0):

It is at least worth mentioning, I was getting a 404 http code despite the fact that I could print data to screen. The problem came when trying to pass POST data between forms.

Long story short, **make sure you have apache rewrite enabled:**

```
apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

OR, look for 'mod_rewrite' under "Loaded Modules" under "apache2handler" in phpinfo().

To **enable apache rewrite:**

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = REQUEST_URI
```

changing between either REQUEST_URI or QUERY_STRING worked for me

Answer (score 0):

if someone read this post again, don't forget check all uppercase and lowercase letter in url