# 404 not found when using htaccess in GoDaddy

Tags: php, codeigniter

After uploading my files in GoDaddy, the only page that can be viewed in my site is my home page, and when I click to other page, a 404 Page Not Found appear.
Here is my .htaccess file written in Sublime Text

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
Options -Indexes 
DirectoryIndex index.php 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|my_assets|images|css|js|fonts|install|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have read some articles that if you write it in notepad or sublimetext, it won't work when uploaded to GoDaddy. I'm not sure if its true.
Do I need some IDE or an editor for .htacces? Or my .htaccess has a missing code or whatever.

Comment: I'd suggest contact GoDaddy support. Do they even allow you to use htaccess?

Comment: Hi Daniel Williams, do I need to ask them first to allow me to use htaccess? Or is there any configurations there that I need to manually turn on/off for htaccess. I've already contacted them, but they don't reply yet.

Comment: hi try this godaddy installation tips for codeigniter https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installation-Tips

Comment: Just a couple of topics found may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615284/puzzled-using-codeigniter-on-godaddy-shared-hosting-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641627/codeigniter-404-cant-find-index-php-only-on-real-server-not-on-virtual-server

Comment: I don't have any clue if they allow htaccess, I'm just suggesting they may not because they are a huge web host, prone to security exploits, and hatches can cause damage if used incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

We do allow .htaccess at GoDaddy. There isn't an issue with using sublime or notepad either, as long as you save it as a .htaccess and not another file extension type. Also make sure if you use notepad that word wrap isn't enabled, that will insert some code that breaks it.